# Valid data in A group- SQL Grouping

Tags: t-sql

May some one please help me how to achieve the below scenario.

two tables one called as driver and one called as electronic.

-- Driver table

```
DECLARE @DRIVER TABLE
(
Parenttype varchar (50),
childtype varchar (50)
)

INSERT @DRIVER

SELECT 'Carbon Composite Resistor','Ceramic %'
```

-- Electronic Table

```
DECLARE @ELECTRONIC TABLE
(
PARENTSKU varchar (50),
ROLLOVER varchar (50),
CHILDSKU varchar (50),
TYPE varchar (50)
)

INSERT @ELECTRONIC

SELECT 'BIN19-1405','LEAD','19-1405','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAM92-140','MERCURY','92-140','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAB45-155','LEAD','45-155','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NIP69-153','SULPHUR','69-153','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'DIP19-1508','LEAD','19-1508','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZQC140012','ROHS','140012','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'LHH543012','ROHS','543012','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'JWC592013','ROHS','592013','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHY846013','ROHS','846013','Carbon Composite Resistor' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZQC140012','ROHS','140012','Ceramic capacitors LARGE' UNION ALL
SELECT 'LHH543012','ROHS','543012','Ceramic capacitors SMALL' UNION ALL
SELECT 'JWC592013','ROHS','592013','Ceramic capacitors MEDIUM' UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHY846013','ROHS','846013','Ceramic capacitors' UNION ALL
SELECT 'MCN8LTC8K','ROHS','8LTC8K','Double-layer capacitors' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRM81150','ROHS','81150','Tantalum capacitors' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRM846013','ROHS','846013','Hybrid capacitors '
```

Here I am looking for output which meet two below condition

**1st: ALL those Parent SKU which contain type which is equal to the Parenttype available in Driver table and rollover other than ROHS**

**2ND: ALL THOSE Parent SKU Records whose rollover are ROHS but only present with parent type but not with Child Type**

Expected Output

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ PARENTSKU  ║ ROLLOVER ║ CHILDSKU ║           TYPE            ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ BIN19-1405 ║ LEAD     ║ 19-1405  ║ Carbon Composite Resistor ║
║ SAM92-140  ║ MERCURY  ║ 92-140   ║ Carbon Composite Resistor ║
║ SAB45-155  ║ LEAD     ║ 45-155   ║ Carbon Composite Resistor ║
║ NIP69-153  ║ SULPHUR  ║ 69-153   ║ Carbon Composite Resistor ║
║ DIP19-1508 ║ LEAD     ║ 19-1508  ║ Carbon Composite Resistor ║
║ MCN8LTC8K  ║ ROHS     ║ 8LTC8K   ║ Double-layer capacitors   ║
║ PRM81150   ║ ROHS     ║ 81150    ║ Tantalum capacitors       ║
║ PRM846013  ║ ROHS     ║ 846013   ║ Hybrid capacitors         ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you show what you have tried so far

Comment: First point seems to be just a `WHERE ROLLOVER!='ROHS'`. 2nd point: Not really clear what you are asking. Following your current rule, I would also get `'ZQC140012','ROHS','140012','Ceramic capacitors LARGE'` and a few others

Comment: 2nd point: when rollover = 'ROHS' then which all  SKU are not present with both parenttype and childtype which is available in the driver table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT  E.PARENTSKU ,
        E.ROLLOVER ,
        E.CHILDSKU ,
        E.TYPE
FROM    @ELECTRONIC AS E
WHERE   ( E.Type IN ( SELECT    D.Parenttype
                      FROM      @DRIVER AS D )
          AND E.ROLLOVER != 'ROHS'
        )
        OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  NULL
                        FROM    @DRIVER AS D
                        WHERE   ( D.Parenttype = E.TYPE )
                                OR ( E.TYPE LIKE D.childtype ) )
```

output

[image]